# NodeJS send socket stream message to C++ engine

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a c++ engine listen on port 1234.

I have a nodeJS pusher listen to a pusher channel. Once a message is received from pusher, I would like the NodeJS to forward or send this message to the c++ engine.

Should I use socket.io stream to make a NodeJS client or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolved, i made a socket.io connection from node to the C++ and worked just fine

The node module is socket.io